# Python Script not running from django shell

Tags: python, django, program-entry-point, django-shell

I'm running a Python script from the Django shell. It was working fine until I added a `main()` function. Now it does not work. When I execute the script, nothing happens (no errors or anything). What am I doing wrong?

From the Django shell, I execute the script like this: `execfile('create_xml.py')`

create_xml.py:

```
import os
import unicodedata

from django.conf import settings
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

from databank.models import Registration

def create_xml(registrations):
    for registration in registrations:
        xml = render_to_string('databank/metadata.xml', {'registration': registration})
        filename = "metadata%s.xml" % (registration.dataset.dataset_id)
        file_path = settings.XML_DATA_FILES
        with open(os.path.join(file_path, filename), 'w') as f:
            f.write(xml.encode('UTF-8'))

def main():
    while True:
        print "For which datasets would you like to create XML files?"
        dsid = input("1: All datasets\t2: Public datasets only\t3: A specific dataset- ")
        if ds == 1:
            # all datasets
            print "Creating XML files for all datasets."
            registrations = Registration.objects.all()
            create_xml(registrations)
            print "All done!"
        elif ds == 2:
            # only public datasets
            print "Creating XML files for public datasets only."
            registrations = Registration.objects.filter(dataset__status='public')
            create_xml(registrations)
            print "All done!"
        elif ds == 3:
            dsid = input("Please input a dataset id: ")
            try:
                r = Registration.objects.get(dataset__dataset_id=dsid)
                print "Creating XML file for dataset %d." % (dsid)
                registrations = [r]
                create_xml(registrations)
                print "All done!"
            except:
                print "Not a valid dataset id. please try again."
        else:
            print "Not a valid option."

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because because `__name__ == '__main__'` is `True` only when the python interpreter is running the file as the program. Try printing `__name__` in the program and then `execfile()` it after changing the comparison. You'll figure out the `__name__` variable. Check [What does if __name__ == "__main__": do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)

Comment: aaah I see, `__name__` is set to `__builtin__` in this case. thanks so much @darkryder